# PDO ／ SELECT COUNT(*) FROM テーブル名と、rowCount();の違い

Tags: php

**質問経緯**
・PDOでレコード件数取得したい
・「SELECT COUNT(*) FROM テーブル名」で取得しようとするもうまくいかない
・しょうがないので、rowCount();で取得

---

**質問1**
・rowCount();って何ですか？
・「`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM テーブル名`」と何が違うのでしょうか？
・PDO独自のメソッド？
・「`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM テーブル名`」は、PDOでは使用できないのでしょうか？

**質問2**
・rowCount();はステータスに対してしか使用できない？
・つまり、一度SQLを発行した後でしか駄目なのでしょうか？(SQLを最低2回書かなければいけない？)

Comment: 私は `select count(*)` を主に使いますが、どのようなコードでどう上手くいかなかったのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> rowCount();って何ですか？

http://php.net/manual/ja/pdostatement.rowcount.php
ここにあるとおり

「PDOStatement::rowCount() は 相当する PDOStatement オブジェクトによって実行された **直近の DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE 文によって作用した行数を返します**。」

です。

> PDO独自のメソッド？

上述のとおりPDOStatementクラスのメソッドです。
なので、

> rowCount();はステータスに対してしか使用できない？
>   つまり、一度SQLを発行した後でしか駄目なのでしょうか？(SQLを最低2回書かなければいけない？)

についてはどちらもYesです（用語は不正確ですが…）。

なお上記リンク先の注意書きに次のように書かれているとおり

「ほとんどのデータベースでは、PDOStatement::rowCount() は SELECT 文によって作用した行数を返しません」

ので、レコード件数の数え上げには適していません。

件数の数え上げ目的であれば普通に `select count(*)` が使えるはずですが、うまくいかないというのであれば何かが間違っています。